# Detect diff in usage of local python module within a repo

Tags: python, github, static-analysis

I have a large python repo called **REPO**.  Within **REPO** is a module **MODULE** that is imported and used throughout **REPO**.  I'm trying to find a way to automatically detect whenever one of the following happens:

1. Someone adds an instance of importing **MODULE** to their file in **REPO**
2. Someone removes/changes an instance of importing **MODULE** in their file in **REPO**
3. Someone changes the way they are using an import of **MODULE** in their file.

Comment: "Reviewers" are a GitHub-specific feature (well, other systems have them as well, but they're not in base Git and every add-on has its own method of picking reviewers). So you'll need a GitHub-specific trick, assuming GitHub as in the tags. I don't know of one off-hand.

Comment: Ah I think maybe I focused on the wrong thing here...in my mind if I have to manually add reviewers every time I detect a change with a script I run manually...that's suboptimal but it's better than nothing.

The part of this I think is hard is how do I detect the diff described in points 1,2,3

Comment: Ah - from Git you can easily detect a change in the *number* of `import.*mymodule` *occurrences* (see `git diff -S --pickaxe-regex`) but that's not nearly good enough (e.g., doesn't work with continued lines). In any case you need a real import analyzer for item 3.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.